# Differences between Objective-C vs. Objective-C 2.0

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I reserved 2 library books which came on the same day. I saw them on the shelf and realized that they were the same except one was about ObjC and one was about ObjC 2.0.

Also, what is the Objective-C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple has an [overview of Objective-C 2.0](http://developer.apple.com/leopard/overview/objectivec2.html) on its Web site, though it's worth noting that the version of Objective-C 2 on the iPhone doesn't include garbage collection. Basically, the differences amount to:

- Garbage collection (on the Mac)
- `for (id object in collection)`
- Properties and dot-syntax
- Changes to the low-level runtime functions

Objective-C++ is a compiler mode that allows you to intermingle C++ code with Objective-C code in the same function body.

Answer (score 2):

A [little wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) told me:

- Objective-C: a C-style programming language with Smalltalk-style messaging.
- [Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B): a GCC front-end which adds to C++ the extensions Objective-C adds to C.
- [Objective-C 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C_2.0): a revision of the Objective-C language that includes modern garbage collection, syntax enhancements, runtime performance improvements and 64-bit support.  Also adds features such as properties and fast enumerators.  Currently only for OSX.